# Ajax, php, код рабочий но данные пропадают через секунду

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Собственно код рабочий и на секунду показывает то что я хочу увидеть, но сразу проподает.

Форма:

```html
<form id="form" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 ">
          <input  name="email"type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Email"  >
        </div> 
   </div>
   <hr/>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input  name="name1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Назва">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input  name="autor1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Автор">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input  name="year1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Рік випуску">
        </div> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  >Відправити</button>
</form>
```

Скрипт:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form").submit(function () { 
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: "catalog_show.php", 
                data: form_data,
         
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
         
                    $("#catalog_table").html(data);
                                        
                }
                 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

catalog_show.php:

echo hi

Хотя с таким скриптом все работает(но мне нужно чтобы он срабатывал не сразу, а при отправки формы):

```js
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "catalog_show.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        $("#catalog_table").html(res);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае форма сабмитит дважды - без перезагрузки аяксом и сразу после срабатывает `get` сабмит формы (стандартный) который, как вы знаете, перезапрашивает страницу с параметрами (queryString). Это происходит из-за того, что событие `$("#form").submit` продолжает распространение (выполнение) после запроса `ajax`. Его необходимо остановить (`return false)`.

```
$("#form").submit(function () { 
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: "catalog_show.php",
        ...
        success: function(res){
            ...
        }
    });
return false; //gimme some magic
});
```